# FLTK Cannot open "image.jpg"

Tags: c++, image, graphics, fltk

I'm making a program on fltk for a uni cpp project and I need to be able to attach an image to an open window. However when the window opens I get the text of "cannot open "(respective image name).jpg(or gif)".My headers/cmake lists are correct and I tried sending the exact same code to a friend that has the same project where he didn't have a problem and attached the image correctly.
Here is the respective code:

```
#include "Simple_window.h" 
#include "Graph.h"        

int main(){
    using namespace Graph_lib;
    Simple_window win(Point(0, 0), 600, 400, "Canvas");
    Image img(Point(100, 100), "image.jpg"); 
    win.attach(img);
    win.wait_for_button();
}
```

And here is the output

[WIndow Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTBSR.png)

Also here are the files

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEdmc.png)

Comment: Maybe `image.jpg` is in the wrong folder. It will only look in the current working directory. It will not search your hard drive, desktop ... Depending on your IDE it could need to be in the same folder as your executable.

Comment: The program will look in the Current Working Directory for `"image.jpg"` as the path has not been specified. What the CWD is depends on how the program is launched.

Comment: how do i find my CWD in vscode?

Comment: You should be able to figure that out by the terminal output.

Comment: The current working directory is probably the `build` folder or a subdirectory of that.